# how to fix Notice: Undefined index: Sections in *\sections.php on line 98

Tags: php, forms, echo

I received the following error message when I tried to show the content in my dashboard. How may I fix it?

the code is

```
       <?php foreach ($sections as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['ht_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Sections'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ht_descr'] ?></td>
                <td>
                <a href="edit_section.php?section_id=<?php echo $row['ht_id'] ?>&operation=edit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>

                <a href=""  class="btn btn-danger delete_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-<?php echo $row['ht_id'] ?>" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
            </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
```

the `ht_id` and the `ht_descr` are good there is nothing wrong with it only the Sections row give me the error

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means? `var_dump($row)` shows what?

Comment: It is case sensitive. Maybe `$row['sections']`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using for each loop, then why you need to address it with row you can do it with $sections
For Ex

`<td><?php echo $sections['ht_id'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sections['Sections'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sections['ht_descr'] ?></td>`

And for the problem of undefined check the spelling of column name, you can debug and check the array of row.

Comment: sorry for the delay. didn't work and I`v check the database and spelling are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the index exists:

```
<?php 
if(isset($row[‘Sections’])) {
echo $row['Sections'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: problem solved thanks all for your replays

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure that source array contains a "Section" key, then you can check it before print it:

```
echo isset($row['Sections']) ? $row['Sections'] : '';
```

Comment: didn't print anything and I couldn't find out what the problem thanks